# Java Array : Unable to store new values into an array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I am getting battery values from a drone. I am able to display the new battery value on JLabel. However, when I am trying to store these battery values into an int array, it is only store the very first battery value on the array. The subsequent array values will only fill up with the first battery value.

I show an output so you will understand what is happening. The first value is getting from drone while the second value indicate the array index. The output clearly show that the array cannot accept new data for unknown reason.

P/S: I have no idea what is best size of array since I am getting values from drone every seconds. So I have declared an int array with size of 9999999. Any idea how can I set an array to its max size to cater the needs of getting continuous battery values from drone? Those values are being used for drawing graph later.

**My code:**

```
public class arDroneFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable, DroneStatusChangeListener, NavDataListener {

      private String text; // string for speech
      private static final long CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10000;
      public ARDrone drone;
      public NavData data;
      public Timer timer = new Timer();
      public int batteryGraphic=0;
      public int [] arrayBatt = new int[9999999];

      public arDroneFrame(String text) {
          this.text=text;          
      }

      public arDroneFrame() {
         initComponents();             
         initDrone();       
      }

      private void initDrone() {
        try {
          drone = new ARDrone();
          data = new NavData();          
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        return;     
      } 
        videoDrone.setDrone(drone);        
        drone.addNavDataListener(this);
}

     public void navDataReceived(NavData nd) { 
         getNavData(nd);    
         int battery = nd.getBattery();  
         cmdListOK.jlblBatteryLevelValue.setText(battery + " %"); 
         //JLabel can get updated & always display new battery values 
      }

     public void getNavData(NavData nd){
          for(int i=0;i<arrayBatt.length;i++){
              batteryGraphic= nd.getBattery();
              arrayBatt[i] = batteryGraphic;
              System.err.println("This is stored battery values : " + arrayBatt[i] + "   " + i + "\n");
          }
     }
}

     public static void main(String args[]) {
          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

              String text = "Welcome!";
              arDroneFrame freeTTS = new arDroneFrame(text);
              freeTTS.speak();

              new arDroneFrame().setVisible(true);
              }
      });
   }
```

**Result:**

```
This is stored battery values : 39   0

This is stored battery values : 39   1

This is stored battery values : 39   2

This is stored battery values : 39   3

This is stored battery values : 39   4

This is stored battery values : 39   5
```

Comment: You're querying the battery's status in a tight loop -- did you expect it to change so fast?

Comment: I was tried to limit the battery level update in 5 seconds but it seems cannot work. I used a timer with the time interval of 5 seconds. So now I am trying focusing on getting battery values store in int array correctly before proceed to fix the timer bug.

Comment: Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) rather than making an arbitrarily large array.

Comment: what is your `NavData`? How frequently the battery value changes?

Comment: We'll need to see more code ([a complete code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The code you've shown doesn't appear to have a problem.

Comment: Karthik, NavData is a class. Inside this class, I am able to retrieve all the drone values from it. The NavData code is available here : [http://javadrone.googlecode.com/hg-history/537f5c119447815b6d4fc48e8a6a6c0e815def21/src/com/codeminders/ardrone/NavData.java]

Comment: Thanks 2016rshah for the suggestion. Yes I will change the array to ArrayList for better performance later.

Comment: Hi Dukeling, I have upload the complete sample code for my project. Hopefully somebody could spot there is the bug caused such problem.

Comment: @DennisQT your problem is very clear. Your `batteryGraphic` is not changing as fast as your loop is running. If you want to debug this,  change `arrayBatt[i] = batteryGraphic;` to `arrayBatt[i] = batteryGraphic + i;` . You will see continuos elements like `x,x+1,x+2 ...`

Comment: @karthik :  Ah I see. So that mean [tag:batteryGraphic] is unable to receive updates as fast as from the for loop? I will give it a try and see what happen after make the changes. Thanks !

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for your help ! It works and I manage to store all the values into ArrayList. However, there are a lot of same duplicate values stored into ArrayList. How can I compare each of every element so that I could only get the different values in ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem lies in this method:**

```
public void getNavData(NavData nd){
      for (int batteryValue : arrayBatt){
           arrayBatt[i] = nd.getBattery();
               System.err.println("This is stored battery values : " + arrayBatt[i] + "   " + i + "\n");
      }
   }
```

You call this method by passing it a `NavData` instance. This means that whatever value `nd` contains for `nd.getBattery()` is being assigned to every index in your array as the loop interates over your battery array.

What you should do, is move the loop outside of the `getNavData(NavData nd)` method, and pass it a new instance of `NavData` for each call. When you couple this with the `ArrayList` suggestion below, you should have a dynamic array of distinct battery values

---

**Side solution**

The way that you have declared this array is **REALLY SCARY**.
You should only use the space you need and NOTHING more.
I know that you are unsure of what size is actually required, but don't go over-board on it.

You should initialize your array with something smaller;

```
public int [] arrayBatt = new int[10000];
```

*As a side note: having your class members as public is generally not recommended*.  You should make them private and create getter/setter methods to retrieve and modify the data, respectively.
Then, have a method that checks to see if your array is full. If it is full, then increase the array size by `n/2`, where `n` is the initial size of your array.

The down-side to this approach is that as your array becomes larger, you are going to spend a lot of time copying the old array to the new array, which is pretty undesirable.

**A better solution**

Would be to use the built-in `ArrayList` library, then just append items to your list and let Java do the heavy lifting.

```
ArrayList<Integer> batteryArray = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

you can add items to your list by simply calling:

```
batteryArray.add(item);
```

The upside to this solution is that:

1. The batteryArray size is handled behind-the-scenes
2. The size of the array is easily retrievable, as well as the elements
3. ArrayList is a very fast storage structure.

---

In your loop to print out battery values, you could make it a lot cleaner by implementing a for-each loop.

- Why are you using `System.err` to print out dialogs for the battery?? This isn't what `System.err` is meant to be used for and violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

  ```
  public void getNavData(NavData nd){
    for (int batteryValue : arrayBatt){
        arrayBatt[i] = nd.getBattery();
        System.err.println("This is stored battery values : " + arrayBatt[i] + "   " + i + "\n");
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: but this is not what he asking for.

Comment: @karthik No it's not, but I do address his question by showing a way that the array can be controlled and get the size to become dynamic

Comment: @EvanBechtol : Hi ! Thanks for solving the array size problem for me. Yeah I do realize the way of how I declare the array size is quite horrible and terrible. I will change after this. Thank you very much. However, do you spot any logic error which the array cannot really store the next values?

Comment: @DennisQT I believe I found the problem. Please check the top of my answer

Comment: @EvanBechtol, thanks ! You are correct. for-each loop is more readable & easier to use instead. Okay thank you again and I will give it a try...see how everything works !

Comment: @EvanBechtol, yes I am aware that System.err is only used for any necessary case. I use System.err to highlight the output for me to check the battery values. 

May I know how do I move the loop outside of the getNavData(NavData nd) method, and pass it a new instance of NavData for each call? Any example for it? Sorry I am quite confused of it. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Can you make an ArrayList of a primitive type? I thought you could only use class types, Eg: `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: @SaviourSelf You are right, my mistake! Thanks for pointing that out. I just corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is some event that is triggered by the drone's hardware.
Your loop runs too fast, probably thousands of times per second so there was not time for any battery change and `nd.getBattery()` returns the same value.

It seems that this is the reason why the values are repeated.

On the other hand, I suspect that `navDataReceived` is called only when the hardware detects a change and this is why it displays the new value. When `getNavData` is called you are running a tight loop that locks the execution and prevents your application from receiving this event while the loop is executing.

You should only store a value when you are notified of some change.

I see your implementation of `getNavData` as fundamentally wrong.

Your 10 million int array is useless in this situation.

I don't know how your application interacts with the drone's hardware but the interface names `DroneStatusChangeListener` and `NavDataListener` suggest that you receive some notification when a change occurs.